# What type of compression fitting do I need?

Tags: water, pipe, dishwasher, fitting

I purchased a GE PLV1817XSS dishwasher and I am trying to connect the water to to the dishwasher intake, but I'm having trouble finding the correct fitting. The water intake is an unthreaded plastic tube that sticks out the back. The [instructions](https://visualizador.serviplus.com.mx/datos_pt/cocc/manuales/PLV1817XSS_MANUALUSUARIO_LAVAVAJILLAS.pdf)<sup>(Spanish)</sup> are extremely vague and simply say to get a 90 degree elbow, but give no indication of what size of anything is needed:

[image: GE PLV1817XSS installation manual excerpt]

I had purchased a [Braided stainless steel water hose](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UH2OIMC) which comes with an elbow (3/8" FCM (Female Compression) x 3/8" MCM (Male Compression) 90° brass elbow), thinking that this was all I needed, but I didn't realize that it lacks the compression nut that goes with it.

The outer diameter of the water inlet tube is 14 mm (measured with a vernier caliper), but when I went to a place that specializes in brass, they said they don't have anything that measures 14 mm, since apparently that isn't a standard size. They had one fitting that is 12.8 mm, which is too small, and another that is about 16 mm, which (I think) is too big. Can anybody give me an idea what I need to get the water connected to this thing? Do I need something else besides a brass fitting that might come in different measurements?

I called the support number listed in the manual and they told me that they wouldn't help me unless I paid for a certified technician to do the installation. Thanks, GE.

[image: dishwasher back]

**Edit: Apparently that tube sticking out the back is *not* the water intake. The water intake is on the front of the dishwasher.**

Comment: "The water intake is an unthreaded plastic tube that sticks out the back," are you sure about that? The water intake should be a brass fitting under the front lip. See page 13 of the PDF.

Comment: @longneck I attached a photo to my question.

Comment: "*The water intake should be a brass fitting under the **front** lip*" ok... I was apparently looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: @longneck Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: So much like the brass fitting shown in Longneck’s answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The water intake is an unthreaded plastic tube that sticks out the back.

Are you sure about that? The water intake should be a brass fitting under the front lip. See page 13 of the PDF.

Comment: If you navigate to https://products.geappliances.com/appliance/gea-specs/PDT845SSJSS   you will find the Installation instructions in English.   I found them with a few minutes of googling.    Yes, the water intake is on the bottom near the front.  Step 16 page 11 shows the connection, but the planning and routing guides discuss how you make sure you have a long enough supply line.

Comment: @DaveM That's a different model.

Comment: Grumble... google changed my search results... I'll come back later and try again.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the compression nut. With that water hose, you should connect it directly to your water supply shutoff valve.

The compression nut is used when you have a copper pipe as your water supply, like this:

[image]

If that's what you have, remove the nut and the copper pipe. Your braided pipe connects to the water supply like this:

[image]

And connects to your dishwasher like this:

[image]

Use the teflon tape ONLY on the threads between the elbow and the dishwasher. The braided hose has a gasket so DO NOT use teflon tape on those threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My pipes are all PVC, however the question is how do I connect the elbow to the dishwasher. I have everything else connected.

Comment: @Mike The last paragraph tells you that.

Comment: The dishwasher has nothing to screw into. It's literally an unthreaded pipe that sticks out the back of the dishwasher.

Comment: Great illustrative photos!